# Why don't here strings in Makefiles using Bash work?

Tags: bash, make, gnu-make

I just solved a problem with my Makefile(s). Make trips over every `<<<` with the error message

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

And I would like to know why. (I am using Bash as `SHELL`)

In my current projects I tried a lot of recipies along the lines of:

```
target:
    read FOO <<< "XXX"; \
    read BAR <<< "YYY"; \
    read BAZ <<< "ZZZ"; \
    someprog -a param0 -b $$FOO -c param1 -d $${BAR} -e param2 -f $${BAZ} >$@
```

Trying this will result in an error for every `<<<` as described at the beginning. My workaround is

```
target.dep:
    echo "XXX YYY ZZZ" >$@

target: %: %.dep
    read FOO BAR BAZ < $<;\
    someprog -a param0 -b $$FOO -c param1 -d $${BAR} -e param2 -f $${BAZ} >$@
```

which means I put my stuff into temporary files which I then read with `<`, which works just fine. When I copy paste my make output to a normal bash prompt, every command works just as expected, even with the `<<<`. I am fairly certain that my problem is, that using the `<<<` operator, i.e. here strings, break something. Why is that and is there a way to make here strings work in Makefiles?

P.S.: Yes, sometimes I feel autotools would be the better choice over make.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

means you’re *not* using bash as your shell, in spite of your expectations to the contrary. bash as `sh` recognises here strings fine (so your `Makefile` would work on Fedora), but for example dash as `sh` doesn’t. Unless told otherwise, Make uses `/bin/sh` as its shell; it ignores your default user shell.

Setting

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

in your `Makefile` should fix things for you; at least, it does for me on a system showing the same symptoms as yours.

> P.S.: Yes, sometimes I feel autotools would be the better choice over make.

Autotools and Make don’t address the same problems; they’re complementary, and using Autotools would still mean using Make...

Comment: It appears to me that we have autotools because doing it with make alone stops being sensible at some point.

Comment: OMG and yes. I just found the commits that removed my SHELL settings. I should have noticed by the error message though :-(

Comment: “make alone stops being sensible at some point” — agreed! Your comment gave the impression you wanted to use Autotools *instead of* Make. (Curious me just ran `wc -l` on all the `Makefile.am` files in my projects directory, and that said I have 82,495 lines of Automake... Oh dear...)

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the error message, the shell that `make` invokes is not `bash` but `/bin/sh`.  `sh` does not generally understand here-strings.

If you set the `make` variable `SHELL` to `/bin/bash` (or whatever the path is for that shell on your system), it will use `bash` instead of `sh`.

See also the relevant GNU `make` documentation about this at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html